# How to remove a class from one set of siblings without affecting other elements with same class

Tags: jquery, tree-traversal

I have the following:

```
<div class="attributes_set_1>
   <label class="attributes"><input type="radio" value="1" /></label>
   <label class="attributes"><input type="radio" value="2" /></label>
   <label class="attributes"><input type="radio" value="3" /></label>
</div>

<div class="attributes_set_2>
   <label class="attributes"><input type="radio" value="1" /></label>
   <label class="attributes"><input type="radio" value="2" /></label>
   <label class="attributes"><input type="radio" value="3" /></label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add an active class to any of the first set of radio buttons when clicked but also remove the class if selecting a different one from the same set. The problem is that I need to be able to select from the next set of radio buttons without removing the active class from any other set.

I've tried several selectors but I think the way to make it work would be by selecting the children of that specific parent class.

How can I select only the siblings of a particular parent class in order to remove the active class?

```
$('.attributes').children().removeClass('active');
```

How can I add the active class to whatever other radio I clicked whether it is part of the same siblings or not once I make the removeClass() work?

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Thanks to anyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this` is the radio button to which you have added the `active` class then you can find the siblings of the parent `label` elements and then remove the class from its input elements

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('input').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.attributes input').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings('.attributes').find('input').removeClass('active');
})
```